# Install Firebird 2.5.9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firebird, ubuntu-18.04

i'm trying to install firebird 2.5.8 in ubuntu 18.04 with no luck 
manual says in number 6

```
SuperServer only installs a /etc/rc.d/init.d/firebird server start script. 

Classic server installs a /etc/xinetd.d/firebird start script or, for older inetd systems, adds an entry to the /etc/inetd file
```

but it is not happening after I run install.sh, it only create opt/firebird files, also not starting service after install.

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/install210.html#rnfbtwo-install-psx

also in https://firebirdsql.org/manual/ubusetup.html it says:
apt-get install firebird2.5-superclassic

but it prints on terminal:

```
E: Impossível encontrar o pacote firebird2.5-superclassic 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'firebird2.5-superclassic' 
E: Não foi possível encontrar o pacote através da expressão regular 'firebird2.5-superclassic'
```

Comment: I think you'll get more and better help if you post your question to the firebird-support mailing list. For Ubuntu is probably better to install Firebird from a Ubuntu repository instead, I'm not sure though if Firebird 2.5 is available directly for Ubuntu 18.04. And make sure you set your locale to English, so you get English error messages, that makes your problem better to understand.

Comment: it's better when u have updated repositories and added mapopa as well. Look  this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5 is very old, but still helpful

Comment: @KonstantinStreletsky doesn't help for me. `apt-cache search firebird2.5-*` returns nothing

Comment: @Ishayahu
did you search firebird2.5 after these two 
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapopa
    sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yes, and find nothing

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-8/, and download `FirebirdSS-2.5.8.27089-0.amd64.tar.gz` and extract/

In the terminal enter

```
cd FirebirdSS-2.5.8.27089-0.amd64
./install.sh
service –status-all
```

You need to verify if Firebird exists in the list of services.

In the terminal enter

```
chmod 777 /localpath/YOURDB.FDB
```

I used on Ubuntu Server LTS 18.04.02

Comment: Hi Wesley! Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer would be much easier to read with some slight formatting adjustments. Try wrapping code or command line commands in double accents (two of this symbol (`) on either side of your code). The output will look something like ``this``.